# android textview fill parent

Tags: android, background, textview

I have a simple ExpandalbeList.  For the group header view, I'm using a simple TextView, I am setting the background of the text to a drawable.  I have the textview parameters set to FILL_PARENT, but the background of the TextView only covers the width of the text.  I realize that I can put this all inside of a Linear Layout, but that just seems like a waste.  isn't there a way to make the bounds of the text view stretch to the edge of the listview?

```
        public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(PulseSearchResults.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setTextSize(16.0f);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_section_group);
        return textView;
    }
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }
```

thx
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that if i set the width of the listview to FILL_PARENT, it solves the issue...